# (Java) how to split an array by a certain value (string)?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, split

I have a list of arrays

```
[Type 1970, Type 1981, Type 1985, Type 1999]
[Type 1985, Type 1970, Type 1985, Type 1999]
[Type 1999, Type 1981, Type 1985, Type 1970]
[Type 1981, Type 1985, Type 1999, Type 1970]
[Type 1985, Type 1970, Type 1981, Type 1999]
```

I would like to split up these arrays while only pulling a specific model type such as "Type 1999" and providing a count.

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
int counter = 0 
for(int i = 0; i < listOfTypes.length; i++){
String[] typesSearch = listOfTypes[i]
if(typesSearch != null) {
    if(typesSearch.equals("Type 1999")); {
counter++;
}
}
```

Ideally the output would be a new array with only a certain element

{Type 1999, Type 1999, Type 1999, Type 1999} and so forth

I think from here I can just use the length() to get a count of the elements inside this newly created array

Comment: `typesSearch.equals("Type 1999")` will always return `false` because one of them is a `String[]` and the other is a `String`. They can never be equal.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have 2-d array

```
    String[][] listOfTypes = {
            {"Type 1970", "Type 1981", "Type 1985", "Type 1999"},
            {"Type 1985", "Type 1970", "Type 1985", "Type 1999"},
            {"Type 1999", "Type 1981", "Type 1985", "Type 1970"},
            {"Type 1981", "Type 1985", "Type 1999", "Type 1970"},
            {"Type 1985", "Type 1970", "Type 1981", "Type 1999"}
    };
```

and to count the occurrance of `Type 1999`

```
    int counter = 0;
    for (String[] typesSearch : listOfTypes) {
        for (String str : typesSearch) {
            if ("Type 1999".equals(str)) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

or using stream

```
    int counter = (int) Arrays.stream(listOfTypes)
            .flatMap(typesSearch -> Arrays.stream(typesSearch))
            .filter(str -> str.equals("Type 1999"))
            .count();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you'd want that; your current code works fine and is efficient.

I guess you can do this:

```
int count = (int) Arrays.stream(listOfTypes)
  .filter(x -> x.equals("Type 1999"))
  .count();
```

If you prefer that style, knock yourself out. Performance-wise and readability wise it really makes no difference. Making an intermediate array with just the `Type 1999` entries **is** however, quite expensive, relative to just counting at any rate. It's also more code. I have no idea why you think it's a better solution vs. just counting.